# How to access HTTPS pages throught SSH tunnel

Tags: http-proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have 2 PC : PC1 & PC2. Both are Linux
PC1 has 2 network interfaces.
The first one give access to some web servers and with the second one, we have a sub-network containing PC1 & PC2
On PC1, there is an SSH client and an SSH server on PC2.
Also I have user permissions on PC1 (can't install something on it) and root permissions on PC2.

From PC2, I'm able to access some of my web servers (through PC1) with http protocol
For this, I set up an SSH tunnel with a command of type "ssh -R ..." from PC1.

Now, I would like to access web servers with https protocol from PC2.
What is the best way to do this ?

First I thought set up a http/https proxy server on PC1 but I don't think it will be possible due to lack of permissions (if you know one which doesn't require install I'm interesting).